# Как добавить отступы между полями форм? Слева, справа, сверху и снизу

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
input[type="text"] {
  width: 220px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.user-adres,
adres1 {
  width: 440px;
}

.user-family {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.user-name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  margin: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.user-fathername {
  position: absolute;
  left: 440px;
  margin: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.user-adres {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.user-mail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 440px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Не могу сооброзить как разделить поля форм и добавить им отступы. margin не работает

Comment: На фото пример как должно быть

Comment: добавьте рабочий фрагмент кода (кнопка < >)

Comment: input[type="text"] {
 width: 220px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.user-adres, adres1 {
 width: 440px;
}

.user-family {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 margin: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}

.user-name {
 position: absolute;
 left: 220px;
 margin: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}

.user-fathername {
 position: absolute;
 left: 440px;
 margin: 10px;
 top: 10px;
}

.user-adres {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.user-mail {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 440px;
 margin: 10px;
}

Answer (score 0):

И не сработают маргины, поскольку у вас абсолютное позиционирование. Как бы вы их не задавали, браузер отрисует инпуты по заданным вами координатам.

Решений несколько:

1. Изменить координаты инпутов так, чтобы одни отстояли дальше от других. CSS-свойства `top, left`
2. Избавиться от позиционирования вообще и использовать нормальную (хоть и не модно это) таблицу, задав ячейкам паддинги. Для поля "адрес" использовать сдвоенную ячейку с атрибутом `colspan="2"`.
3. Использовать Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для разметки формы css-grid, вот ваш пример:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#adress {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

#container input {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input id="adress">
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
</div>
```

Как видите тут margin работает!